# как передать параметр id

Tags: javascript

Если можно то как передать параметр id в функцию move() ?

```
<div class="block1" id="circle" onMouseDown="move()" onKeyDown="stop()">

function move(id) {
document.addEventListener('mousemove', moved(id));
}
```

Comment: move(/* Здесь id */); function move(id) { /* Здесь код */ }

Comment: нужно чтобы из id передавался из тега при нажатии на блок

Comment: `<div class="block1" id="circle" onclick="move()" onKeyDown="stop(this)">` `function move( block ) { console.log(block.id); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно передавать this в качестве аргумента функции.

```js
function move(evt) {
evt.innerHTML = evt.id;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1" id="circle" onclick="move(this)" style="font-size:100px;">•</div>
```

Или использовать прототипы

```js
Object.prototype.move = move;
function move() {
this.innerHTML = this.id;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1" id="circle" onclick="this.move()" style="font-size:100px;">•</div>
```